# Determining if a set is a Generating Set given a known group rank

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

Suppose I have a finitely generated group $G$ of known rank $n$, and a set $\{s_i\}$ of $n$ group elements. Are there some simple necessary and sufficient conditions to determine whether $s_i$ generates $G$? (Suppose that I don't have any known generating set which I can try to generate with the $\{s_i\}$.)

For example, I think this is a necessary condition:

- $\forall s \in \{s_i\} \; \;\not \exists g \in G \; : \; \langle s\rangle \subset \langle g \rangle$

Is it also sufficient?

Comment: Your condition is not necessary, you can always take $g=s^{-1}$. You probably mean that $<s>$ is a proper subgroup of $<g>$. In any case, this condition is neither necessary nor sufficient.

Comment: @MoisheCohen - you're right, that's what I meant. I'm pretty sure the condition is necessary. Suppose $s = g^2$. Then you cannot generate $g$ except by using the other $s_i$. But then that makes $s$ redundant, and so your generating set is equivalent to one of cardinality $n-1$, hence not a generating set for a rank $n$ group.

Comment: No, this does not make $s$ redundant.

Comment: @MoisheCohen - if the other $\{s_i\}$ generate $g$, then they also generate $g^2 = s$. But maybe you need a combination of $s$ with the other $s_i$ to make $g$? I suppose this could happen.

Comment: Exactly! Just think about the case of a finite cyclic group of prime order.

Comment: Something you should contemplate: There exist infinite finitely generated divisible groups, i.e. groups $G$ where for every $h\in G$ and every $n>1$ there exists  $g\in G$ such that $h=g^n$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen - I don't find that example enlightening, because in that case, what I've written is a necessary and sufficient condition. And it's a group of rank $1$. Is there a simple example where this condition is not necessary, or not sufficient?

Comment: No, such groups need not be rank 1. There are nonabelian examples of rank 2.

Comment: What do you mean by the "rank" of a group? Do you mean the minimal number $n$ such that $G$ can be generated by $n$ elements? Or do you just meant that $G$ *can* be generated by $n$ elements?

Comment: @user1729 the minimal number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $\langle a, t; t^{-1}at=a^2\rangle$ has rank two and is generated by the set $\{a^2, t\}$. However, $\langle a^2\rangle\lneq\langle a\rangle$ (this follows from Magnus' Freiheitssats*, as $\langle a\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$). Therefore, your condition is neither necessary or sufficient.

I would suspect that in general there does not exist an algorithm to determine, for a group $G$ of rank $n$, if a given $n$-element subset of generates the whole group $G$. However, I cannot come up with a proof at the moment...

*See Magnus, Karrass and Solitar, *Combinatorial Group Theory*, 1965